# In this scenario, discuss which join operation can help to retrieve the records from multiple tables

Tags: database, memory-management

Consider a scenario, there are three tables name ‘X’, ‘Y ‘and’ Z’ with schemes X (u, v, w), Y (l, u, m, n, o, p) and Z (r, s, t, u, q), These tables have a common attribute or field. We want to retrieve the data from these tables.

In this scenario, discuss which join operation can help to retrieve the records from multiple tables.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. If you have a question, please go ahead and ask it; Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, *not* a forum, see what is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -1):

Virtual university cs403 GDB